# Which is the most early type star with a planet discovered by radial velocity method?

Tags: planet

We have discovered planets in  Beta_Pictoris(A6V)[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Pictoris_b) and Fomalhaut alpha(A3v)[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fomalhaut). 
However they were discovered by direct images.

There should be an stellar type limit by RV? 
 
What is the most early type ever found?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct images"? Eclipses? 
And what do you mean by "most early type ever found"? If we observed O0 stars?

Comment: direct image means we see the planet directly. You can see two images at those two links above. early type, I mean ,stellar classification. It is not easy to find early type star host by a exo-planet via radial velocity.

Comment: 'What is the most early type ever found" is too general. Please, edit the question. Also about the first point, you should say something like "they were directly observable".

Comment: It is not "too general". We have only found no more than 2k EXOPLANETS.

Comment: direct imaging is one of the methods of discovering exoplanets. you can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_detecting_exoplanets

Comment: I didn't know about the "direct image" terminology. Then you could add a link. About the "too general" issue, you didn't catch my point. You want to know what is the earliest stellar type hosting a planet inferred by radial velocity, right?

Comment: yes. generally it is difficult to discover a early type star hosting a planet because early type stars are more massive and have less absorption lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this, and other questions of its kind about exoplanets, can easily be found at the website http://exoplanets.org/  This site contains a very authoritative catalogue of exoplanet discoveries and has tools to enable tables and plots of many variables to be constructed.

For example, to handle your question, I produced the following plot for exoplanets *discovered using the doppler radial velocity technique*. This shows effective temperature of the parent star on the x-axis, versus projected exoplanet mass $M\sin i$. The the hottest star with an RV-identified exoplanet (on the website, you can click on the points) is HD113337, an F6V-type star discovered by [Borginiet et al. (2013)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013arXiv1310.1994B). The next hottest is HD103774, which is given a slightly earlier spectral type of F5V. These two are joint hottest within their uncertainties. Just a touch cooler is Tau Boo.

It is difficult to find exoplanets around high-mass *main sequence* stars using the doppler method because of the paucity of strong, narrow spectral lines. Most of what we know is from observations of subgiant stars - i.e. stars that *would have been* early-type stars on the main sequence, but which have cooler photospheres after they have left the main sequence. HD102956, mentioned in another answer, is an example if this - i.e. it *was* an early-type A star on the main sequence.

[image: Host temperature vs planet mass]

Comment: how do you select the x-axis range? I tried your way, but found the x-axis could be larger than 7000.

Answer (score 2):

[HD 103774 b](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/hd_103774_b/), detected by radial velocity, orbits a star of spectral type F5V according to [The Extrasolar Planet Encyclopeadia](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/all_fields/?f=%22radial%22%20IN%20detection%20OR%20%22astrometry%22%20IN%20detection).

[HD 102956 b](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/hd_102956_b/), detected by radial velocity, [orbits a spectral type A subgiant](http://iopscience.iop.org/2041-8205/721/2/L153/pdf/2041-8205_721_2_L153.pdf), the star of the "earliest" type harboring a planet detected by radial velocity, I could find (as of May 2014).

The entry for
[Kepler-88 c](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/kepler-88_c/) around a spectral type B star (according to the catalog as of May 2014) appears to be incorrect, or encodes something else, [the star should be classified as spectral type G6V](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4335v2.pdf).

Comment: About Kepler-88, also the star is 1 solar mass.

Comment: sigh, the discovery paper(Johnson et al, 2010) of HD102956B did not mention any spectral thing. There is no spectrum or spectral line at all.

Comment: HD 102956b (note the small letter) was discovered by the RV method, but it is a subgiant with a temperature of about 5000K. It *was* an early-type main sequence star. Kepler 88 was of course not discovered by the RV method (as the name suggests) and is cooler than the Sun.